# How to check from a list which check boxes have been selected and which are not in protractor using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to write an end to end test using protractor and i want get the names from a list to check which check boxes have been selected which one's are not. 
I can check using isSelected() to check the state of the checkbox but how do i get the list of the names corresponding to it.
This is what i have i want get the label Option 1 and option 2 one by one to see if it is selected or not:

```html
<ul _ngcontent-c8="" class="children" style="">
<li _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8 " ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
<input _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8" id="all" type="checkbox">
<label _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8" for="all">Option 1</label>
</li>
<li _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8 " ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
<input _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8" id="all" type="checkbox">
<label _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8" for="all">Option 2</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any help and suggestion will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two approaches you can try but have not actually ran either of them myself. They both involve getting all list items in that `ul` first and both are written using the async/await syntax.

**option1**

```
    let checkedNames = [];
    //iterate over all list items
    await element.all(by.xpath('ul[@class="children"]//li')).each(async (li) => {

        //if checkbox is selected then get label text and add to array
        let chkboxIsSelected = await li.element(by.tagName('input')).isSelected();
        if (chkboxIsSelected) {
            let lableTxt = await li.element(by.tagName('label')).getText();

            //Add lable text to array of labels
            checkedNames.push(lableTxt);
        };
    })
```

**Explanation**
`element.all(by.xpath('ul[@class="children"]//li'))` will return an elementFinder array and there are several methods we can call on element finder arrays, all of them listed [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder). `.each` is one of those methods and what it will do is iterate over the element finder array and run a function on each element. It needs to have the element passed into the function in order to run.

The syntax for this would be as follows

```
eleArray.each(function(elementInArray){

})
```

We can declare this function using [arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and as it is an array of list items we are iterating over we can rename the parameter being passed into the function as 'li' to be more descriptive.

```
eleArray.each((li) => {

})
```

Also, as I am using the async/await syntax instead of the promise manager I add the keyword async before all of functions that contain an asynchronous opertation, in your case checking if checkbox is selected in browser and getting text from input field.

**option2**

```
    let allListItems = await element.all(by.xpath('ul[@class="children"]//li'));

    //filter out all of the list items that contain unchecked checkboxes
    let itemsWithSelectedChkbox = await allListItems.filter(async li => {
        return await li.element(by.tagName('input')).isSelected();
    });

    //convert the array of list items into an array which contains
    let textForAllCheckedBoxes = await itemsWithSelectedChkbox .map(async li => {
        return await li.element(by.tagName('label')).getText();
    })

    console.log(`The test associated with all the checked checkboxes is ${textForAllCheckedBoxes}`);
```

Hope these are of some use to you but let me know if there issues!

Comment: The first one worked like a charm thank you. The second one is not returning the correct thing and just returns The test associated with all the checked checkboxes is[object Promise],[object Promise]

Comment: Good to know! I think I mistakenly had a space before the .map which may have affected the second answer but glad the first one worked for you

Comment: Can you explain what each(async (li) is really doing in the first option ?

Comment: @Gee Added an explanation to my answer there but let me know if anything is still unclear!